# The content of the arraylist does not display as expected in another intent?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have two Activity: MainActivity and ContentActivity.

MainActivity (Contain "title" and "content" on 1 ListView take data from ContentActivity)

When I click on 1 item in ListView then "title" and "content" show on ContentActivity. Then click save button then the data is saved.

But when I click on item at item at position 2 in ListView then "content" of item at position 1 changed.

So, How to fix above problem ?

This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListNote;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter
Note _note;
String _content;

listViewNote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String title = arrayListNote.get(position);
                String content = _content;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("content", content);

                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        _note = (Note) data.getSerializableExtra("noteContent"); // noteContent from ContentActivity
        _content = _note.getContent(); // getContent() in Note.java class
        arrayListNote.add(_note.getTitle()); // getTitle() in Note.java class
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

ContentActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    edtTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra("title"));
    edtContent.setText(intent.getStringExtra("content"));

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SetContent();
        }
    });
}

private void SetContent() {
    String title= edtTitle.getText().toString();
    String content= edtContent.getText().toString();

    Note _note = new Note(title, content);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("noteContent", _note);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: You are having a list of titles, but only one single content. Is this the problem?

Comment: That may be the problem, but how to get the content separately ?

Comment: Just like what you did with the titles, make it an `ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks u. I was create 2 arraylist save _content varible, then problem was fixed.